# Javascript, fetch a url instead of a direct file path

Tags: javascript, web

This works fine:

```js
fetch("./xml/Stories.xml").then((response) => {
  response.text().then((xml) => {
    xmlContent = xml;
```

But I would like to get my data from a website which has a link that only displays the xml, how would I go about retrieving the data through a link instead of a direct file path?

I.E:

```js
fetch("https://Example.com/").then((response) => {
  response.text().then((xml) => {
    xmlContent = xml;
```

Comment: it means there is no XML file in your give url path

Comment: There's not enough information here about what you're trying to do. What happens when you try your code? Are you getting any errors reported? If the URL is for a different domain to the one running your JS, there are [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) issues to consider.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

What you are trying to do is called Web scraping. You have to scrape out the link you need from the webpage before you try to `fetch` it's XML content.

While scraping is generally a bad idea, it is certainly possible. Find out a pattern or a element ID / class name which is present on the element containing the link and use a HTTP request to first fetch the web page's HTML content:

```js
const request = require('request');
request('http://stackabuse.com', function(err, res, body) {  
    console.log(body); // The HTML content
});
```

Then you use a HTML parser library like [cheerio](https://cheerio.js.org/) to turn the raw HTML string into traversable objects and get the link you need; `fetch` that link and you have your XML content.

The downside to web scraping is that if the owner of the webpage decides to edit his HTML content, it will probably make your web scraper stop working because the pattern you matched for the link will no longer be valid.

Comment: This was what I was looking for, thank you